# My tabs on the dropdown menu for html

Tags: html, css, styles

I have been creating a website for the school and it consist of a hoverable drop down menu.

The problem is that when ever I hover over the menu the drop down items are not aligned with the dropdown tabs

Here is an image to show you [image]

Comment: What do you have so far? It's hard to troubleshoot without seeing any code.

Comment: Post your code @Bill Fire

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your problem is mainly around **box positioning**. You must always specify your content position when using `absolute` positioning. This will avoid making your submenu flying around, instead of being exactly where you want it to. Also, make sure that the parent element has `relative` position, so that your submenu may inherit box properties from it.

```
.firstlevel-menu-item {
    position: relative;
}
.my-submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;             /* 100% of firstlevel menu's height */
    left: 0;               /* align to firstlevel menu's left side */
    width: 100%;           /* width of firstlevel menu */
}
```

Aligning the content to the end of the parent's box should solve your issue.

There goes a JSFiddle for [enlightenment](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lukv70m/2/).

I suggest you to search a bit more about box positioning, since it is of critical importance for building dropdown menus and a variety of other features that would rely on absolute/relative positioning.

Comment: Down voted: You can't tell the root of the problem from the information given. "You must always specify your content position when using `absolute` positioning"- this is not true

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Due to the information given, by using an example and specifying  my point, don't you think it is a valid answer? Must admit: since there's no code from @Bill Frie, my answer was mainly based on experience. "Seen this before" kind of point